# Is there maximum amount of salary for postdoc?

Tags: united-states, salary

I'm a Ph.D. researcher at a company, and my company wants to send me to a laboratory for postdoc training.

In this case, is there maximum amount of salary for postdoc?

Of course my company will fund me for the postdoc position, but I realized that postdocs salary is around $50k in many cases.

Comment: And the lab is at Harvard.

Comment: Will you stay an employee of the company? I.e., will you be a visiting researcher or will this be an actual postdoc position of the university?

Comment: Expected position is an actual postdoc, whose project is funded by my original company. For more information, it would be appreciated that you can explain in both cases, visiting researcher and actual postdoc.

Comment: I can't write an answer because I'm not familiar with the US system in general and Harvard specifically. However, if you are employed by the university, their regulations for salary would apply to you. It's probable that there is a standard salary and also the possibility to deviate from that standard salary in exceptional cases. In practice, there will be an upper limit, but it doesn't have to be around $50k. You should talk to the university administration about this.

Comment: If you care about money, don't do your PostDoc.

Comment: No, there is not a "maximum salary", in that as far as I know an employer can pay you as much as they like. But I don't think that's what you meant to ask. What do you actually want to know?

Comment: This seems either a misunderstanding or a bizarre situation. Many times that I've seen over the years staff members of companies are sent by the company to do a PhD or a post-doc somewhere else. They have always remained employees of that company, since the company generally wants them to come back with new skills and knowledge to use on the job. Terminating you to go do a post-doc at Harvard is definitely not a good way to be sure you come back. You should remain an employee of the company, with a salary commensurate with your current position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the United States there are no general regulations for such things. Salaries are determined by the people who fund them (with some room for negotiation in most cases). For post-docs funded by the government (federal or state) there will be regulations that must be followed, but for privately funded positions it is up to the funder.

On the other hand, Harvard, being a private institution, is free to impose its own regulations on research in its own labs, so you could check with Harvard to see if that is an issue. I doubt very much that such would be the case, however.

If your company is funding the research and funding you, then your company can, in theory, pay you whatever it wants. Of course, if you are earning more than the PI on the project there might be some resentment, but that would be a personal thing.